# Why looping in Roulette Wheel Selection is stop when First Cumulative value >= Random Value

Tags: c#, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

In this article [Test Run K-Means++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt185575.aspx) he use C# code and Roulette Wheel Selection to get next Centroid

there is a code that implement Roulette Wheel Selection

```
while (sanity < data.Length * 2)
{
    cumulative += dSquared[ii] / sum;
    if (cumulative >= p && used.Contains(ii) == false)
    {
        newMean = ii; // the chosen index
        used.Add(newMean); // don't pick again
        break; // WHY BREAK ?? THERE IS ANOTHER BIGGER CUMULATIVE VALUES
    }
    ++ii; // next candidate

    if (ii >= dSquared.Length) 
        ii = 0; // past the end

    ++sanity;
}
```

but why break when meet first true condition in here :

```
if (cumulative >= p && used.Contains(ii) == false)
```

why not looping until index 19 ???

N : 20 item

Random value = 0,817325359590969

I compare the result from the code with Excel : [Result if not stop at index 16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbUDL.png)

can anyone explain to me the answer of this question ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you want a **weighted random** sampling.

Otherwise, you would always choose the last value.